# First time setting a new position of a UIView, it jumps to the top of the screen

Tags: ios, swift

I build a little iOS App.

In this App I move a UIView to different places and show it with the isHidden attribute. This is not an animation. The View is hidden and when I press a button the View moves to a specific position and will be shown there (`isHidden = false`) It works fine but when I hit the button the first time the view appears at the top of the screen.

I only use autolayout of the left, the right, the height and the width. Not the top or bottom. So I don't know why the first time the view appearse at the top of the screen. I already checked the right position. The code:

`vErgebnis.frame.origin.y = pos_y`

Many thanks

Comment: If you are using autolayout you shouldn't manipulate the `frame` - You should manipulate the autolayout constraints to put the view where you want it. The view does need a top or bottom constraint, otherwise autolayout can't figure out where to put it, so it ends up at the top of the screen.

Answer (score 0):

As @Paulw11 says, you should not mix auto layout and frame manipulation. To do what you want, I would suggest adding a constraint to the top of the view. I'd then link that constraint to a property on your view controller and when you click the button, change the value of the constraint's `constant` property to move the view up or down.

Comment: Ok, I will try this. What is the right way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

If you will use autolayout, you could not set a frame rect. You can one item of four combinations. And change constraint value on button click. For x-direction change leading and trailing. For y-direction change top and bottom constraint value.

1. leading, top, width, height constraints.
2. trailing, bottom, width, height constraints.
3. leading, bottom, width, height constraints.
4. trailing, top, width, height constraints.

Another hand, if you want to use a frame then follow those steps.

1. first hidden your view.
2. set your desired position.
3. after that visible your view.